Найти произведение всех элементов четных и кратных 7
Найти произведение всех элементов четных и кратных 7

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Терминология:

Чётные числа - это числа, остаток от деления которых на 2 равен 0
Кратные 7 - это у которых остаток от деления на 7 равен 0

Что нужно сделать:

Отобрать числа, удовлетворяющие этим уловиям
Перемножить их все между собой


Если я правильно помню, так как 2 и 7 простые числа - можно сразу искать кратность от их произведения, то есть от 14

@mrgervant Это уже оптимизация, но таки да )
